# Some error with integrating Authorize.net in Magento

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I need to integrate Authorize.net integration in Magento.
I have entered correct API login Id and Transaction key. also Test Mode as "No".

I have to integrate for UK country.
So set Merchant Country as UK.

I am getting this error `"The supplied currency code is either invalid, not supported, not allowed for this merchant or doesn't have an exchange rate."`

in `[request]` array from log file, `[x_currency_code] => GBP`, `[x_country] => GB`, `[x_ship_to_country] => GB`

Set Accepted currency as pound also store currency is pound.

still getting error.

so what could be the issue?

Comment: The error message says it all. Contact Authnet support and make sure your account is set up properly to use non-USD currencies.

Comment: Test account I have created and set up for that at `https://developer.authorize.net/testaccount/` with country UK . but still error is there

Comment: Or any other solution like, I have set `Default display currency` as pound. and `base currency` for online transaction purpose set as dollar. then in that case payment working but, currency display in cart is dollar. so any solution for  this?